# strategy.position_avg_price returns "NaN" on alert when triggered in Pinescript

Tags: view, pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5, trading

My code on trading view pine script is returning me "NaN" for strategy.position_avg_price when alert is triggered.

It works when I back test it. However when I test it live, it is giving me "NaN" value.

[Alert message with "NaN" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2wcF.png)

I am trying to place a stop loss using strategy.position_avg_price mins or plus nLoss
However, strategy.position_avg_price keeps returning me "NaN" when alert is triggered after I enter the trade.

This is how I define my stop-loss value

```
//Define stop loss levels for long position
long_stop_level := strategy.position_avg_price - nLoss//close-nLoss
```

This is how I enter a trade.

```
//Enters long trade
if entry_long
    alert_string = pc_id + ',' + 'buy' + ',' + symbol + ',' + 'sl=' + str.tostring(long_stop_level) + ',' + 'risk=' + str.tostring(posSize) 
    alert(alert_string, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

I expect strategy.position_avg_price to return the correct value just as I had backtested it.

This is how my alert setting is.
[Alert setting on tradingview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOqcY.png)

I am willing to pay a small amount for the correct solution.

Sharing my entire code here so that u guys can backtest it yourself. Run this on 1 minute chart and set alert:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5
strategy('Testing Alert for NaN error', overlay=true, currency=currency.USD, initial_capital=10000, slippage=15)

//==============================================================================

//==============================================================================
//BACKTEST DATE RANGE - Select Dates
//==============================================================================
//Input for date window
startDay = input.int(defval=9, title='Start Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='Start Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input.int(defval=2023, title='Start Year', minval=1970)
endDay = input.int(defval=1, title='End Day', minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input.int(defval=1, title='End Month', minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input.int(defval=2025, title='End Year', minval=1970)

//Submit date window
startDate = timestamp(startYear, startMonth, startDay, 00, 00, 00)  // backtest start date
endDate = timestamp(endYear, endMonth, endDay, 23, 59, 59)  // backtest end date
dateRange() =>  // specify where date range is true
    time >= startDate and time <= endDate ? true : false



//==============================================================================

//==============================================================================
//MONEY MANAGEMENT - ATR (Take profit at 1.0 ATR and Stop Loss at 1.5 ATR)
//==============================================================================
//Enter intial capital and percentage risk inputs
percentRisk = input.float(title='Risk Per Trade', defval=0.1, minval=0.001, maxval=0.1)

//Enter ATR inputs

atrLength = input(title='atr' , defval=10)
atrMulti_Profit = input(title='Atr Profit Multiple', defval=1.0)
atrMulti_Loss = input(title='Atr Loss Multiple', defval=20)

//ATR function
truncate(number, decimals) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, decimals)
    int(number * factor) / factor
atr = truncate(ta.atr(atrLength), 5)

//Get position size
posSize = math.round(strategy.initial_capital * percentRisk / (atrMulti_Loss * atr))*0.01
//==============================================================================

//==============================================================================
//INDICATOR 1 - Trigger (C1 - Confirmation 1)
//==============================================================================
//Donchian Channel



basePeriods = input.int(5, minval=1, title='Base Line Length')

donchian(len) =>
    math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

IchimokubaseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

plot(IchimokubaseLine, color=color.new(color.white, 0), title='Ichimoku baseline')


Ind_1_L = close > IchimokubaseLine[1]
Ind_1_S = close < IchimokubaseLine[1]

//==============================================================================


//==============================================================================
//ENTRY CONDITIONS - Submit Orders
//==============================================================================
//Asks user if want to include Long/Short trigger condition
ShortSignal = input(false, 'Tick to include Short Trades?')


//Long and short strategy conditions
entry_long = strategy.position_size <= 0 and dateRange() and Ind_1_L 
entry_short = strategy.position_size >= 0 and dateRange() and Ind_1_S and ShortSignal
plotshape(entry_long, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar, text='Buy')
plotshape(entry_short, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar, text='Sell')

//Store ATR and Price upon entry of trade.
entry_atr = float(0.0)  //set float
entry_atr := strategy.position_size == 0 or entry_long or entry_short ? atr : entry_atr[1]

alertcondition(close >= open, title='Alert on Green Bar', message='Green Bar!')

//Submit long and short orders based on entry conditions
if entry_long
    strategy.entry(id='Long Entry 1', direction=strategy.long, qty=posSize, when=dateRange())
if entry_short
    strategy.entry(id='Short Entry 1', direction=strategy.short, qty=posSize, when=dateRange())
//==============================================================================

//==============================================================================
//TAKE PROFIT & STOP LOSS VALUES
//==============================================================================
//Calculate stop loss and take profit distance (in price)
nLoss = entry_atr * atrMulti_Loss

//Find long take profit and stop loss levels
long_stop_level = float(0.0)  //set float
long_stop_level := strategy.position_avg_price - nLoss//close-nLoss

//Find short take profit and stop loss levels
short_stop_level = float(0.0)  //set float
short_stop_level := strategy.position_avg_price + nLoss//close+nLoss

plotchar(strategy.position_avg_price , 'Strategy Position Avg_Price', '', location=location.top)
plotchar(strategy.position_avg_price[1] , 'Strategy Position Avg_Price[1]', '', location=location.top)
plotchar(strategy.opentrades , 'Strategy Open Trade', '', location=location.top)

//Plot stop loss and profit level on graph; hide levels when no trade
plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 or entry_long or entry_short ? na : long_stop_level, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 or entry_long or entry_short ? na : short_stop_level, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)

//==============================================================================



//==============================================================================

//==============================================================================
//ALERT CONDITIONS - For Autotrading (pineconnector)
//==============================================================================
// PineConnector Settings
pc_id = input.string(title='License ID', defval='6608763584725', group='PineConnector Settings', tooltip='This is your PineConnector license ID')
pc_prefix = input.string(title='MetaTrader Prefix', defval='', group='PineConnector Settings', tooltip='This is your broker\'s MetaTrader symbol prefix')
pc_suffix = input.string(title='MetaTrader Suffix', defval='', group='PineConnector Settings', tooltip='This is your broker\'s MetaTrader symbol suffix')
pc_limit = input.bool(title='Use Limit Order?', defval=true, group='PineConnector Settings', tooltip='If true a limit order will be used, if false a market order will be used')
//pc_spread = input(title="Spread (Broker comm)", defval=1, type=input.float, group="PineConnector Settings", tooltip="This is your broker's spread where they earn commissions")

// Generate PineConnector alert string
plotchar(long_stop_level, 'Long_Stop_Level', '', location=location.top)
plotchar(short_stop_level, 'Short_Stop_Level', '', location=location.top)
plotchar(Ind_1_S, 'Donchain Short', '', location=location.top)
plotchar(Ind_1_L, 'Donchain Long', '', location=location.top)





//pc_entry_alert(direction, price, sl, tp) =>
    //pc_id + "," + direction + "," + symbol + "," + price + "sl=" + tostring(sl) + ",tp=" + tostring(tp) + ",risk=" + tostring(posSize)
    //pc_id + "," + direction + "," + symbol + "," + price + "sl=" + tostring(sl) + "risk=" + tostring(pc_risk)

//sl_inp = ta.sma(close,5)
//stop_level = (strategy.position_avg_price == "NaN") ? (close * (1 - sl_inp)) : (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp))


var symbol = pc_prefix + syminfo.ticker + pc_suffix

//Close short position once Ind_1_L is triggered
if Ind_1_L and strategy.position_size<0
    alert_stringCloseShort = pc_id + ',' + 'closeshort' + ',' + symbol
    alert(alert_stringCloseShort, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

//Enters long trade
if entry_long
    alert_string = pc_id + ',' + 'buy' + ',' + symbol + ',' + 'sl=' + str.tostring(long_stop_level) + ',' + 'risk=' + str.tostring(posSize) 
    alert(alert_string, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
 

//Close Long position once Ind_1_S is triggered
if Ind_1_S and strategy.position_size>0
    alert_stringCloseLong = pc_id + ',' + 'closelong' + ',' + symbol
    alert(alert_stringCloseLong, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

//Enters short trade
if entry_short
    alert_string = pc_id + ',' + 'sell' + ',' + symbol + ',' + 'sl=' + str.tostring(short_stop_level) + ',' + 'risk=' + str.tostring(posSize)
    alert(alert_string, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)



//==============================================================================
//EXIT CONDITIONS - Submit Orders
//==============================================================================
//Submit exit orders on static profit and loss (Exits based on the stoploss set)
strategy.exit('TP/SL 1', 'Long Entry 1', stop=long_stop_level, limit=na)
strategy.exit('TP/SL 1', 'Short Entry 1', stop=short_stop_level, limit=na)

strategy.exit('TP/SL 2', 'Long Entry 2', stop=long_stop_level, limit=na)
strategy.exit('TP/SL 2', 'Short Entry 2', stop=short_stop_level, limit=na)

//Submit exit orders on exit indicator - Exit 1 & 2 (Exits based on our indicator)
strategy.close(id='Long Entry 1', comment='Exit 1 L1', when=Ind_1_S and dateRange())
strategy.close(id='Short Entry 1', comment='Exit 1 S1', when=Ind_1_L and dateRange())

//==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the error is simple. When you call `strategy.entry` the position will not immediatelly opened. The script engine just send entry order and the position will be opened on next script update. Only on this update there are strategy.position_avg_price will be not NaN.
You can try to use different condition for issue the alert:

```
//Enters long trade
if strategy.position_size[1] <= 0 and strategy.position_size > 0
    alert_string = pc_id + ',' + 'buy' + ',' + symbol + ',' + 'sl=' + str.tostring(long_stop_level) + ',' + 'risk=' + str.tostring(posSize) 
    strategy.entry(id='Long Entry 1', direction=strategy.long, qty=posSize, when=dateRange(), alert_message = alert_string)
```